# Post from front-end only by logged in users, form posts as "posted by: <logged-in user's username>"

Tags: posts, customization, front-end

I've handrolled a form for posting from the front-end, with some custom functions that I needed. However, I've made the form only accessible when a user is logged in, and I'd like to have the articles show up as being posted by that user. Thoughts?? Here is my current code:

backend:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && ($_POST['action']== 'new_post')) {
    $has_errors = false;

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $tablature = $_POST['tablature'];
    $performer = $_POST['performer'];
    $composer = $_POST['composer'];
    $submitter = $_POST['submitter'];
    $cat = array( $_POST['cat'] );

    if(!isset($title)) { echo '<div class="error">Title required.</div>'; $has_errors = true; }
    if(!isset($tablature)) { echo '<div class="error">Description required.</div>'; $has_errors = true; }
    if(!isset($performer)) { echo '<div class="error">Performer required.</div>'; $has_errors = true; }
    if(!isset($composer)) { echo '<div class="error">Composer required.</div>'; $has_errors = true; }
    if($cat == -1) { echo '<div class="error">Please select a category.</div>'; $has_errors = true; }

    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
    if (!$has_errors){
    // Save <title>  by: <performer>
    $title .= " by " .$performer;

    // Save Composed by: <composer> Performed by: <performer> <tablature>
    $content = "<h4>Composed by: ".$composer."</h4><h4>Performed by: ".$performer."</h4><p>Submitted by: ".$submitter."</p><br/>".$tablature;

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_category' => $cat,
        'post_status' => 'draft'
    );
    wp_insert_post($new_post);

    // save email and submitter as post meta in custom fields
    wp_redirect( home_url('/thank-you/') );
}
```

}

frontend:

```
<div id="postbox">
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">
<p><label for="submitter">Submitted By</label><br />
<input type="text" id="submitter" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="submitter" class=”required” minlength="3" />
</p>
<p><label for="email">Email Address</label><br />
<input type="text" id="email" value="" tabindex="2" size="20" name="email" />
</p>
<p><label for="title">Song Title</label><br />
<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="3" size="20" name="title" class=”required” minlength="3" />
</p>
<p><label for="composer">Composed By</label><br />
<input type="text" id="composer" value="" tabindex="4" size="20" name="composer" class=”required” minlength="3" />
</p>
<p><label for="performer">Performed By</label><br />
<input type="text" id="performer" value="" tabindex="5" size="20" name="performer" class=”required” minlength="3" />
</p>
<p><label for="tablature">Song Body</label><br />
<textarea id="tablature" tabindex="6" name="tablature" cols="50" rows="6" class=”required” minlength="50"></textarea>
</p>
 <p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=7&taxonomy=category&exclude=5&class=required' ); ?></p>
<p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="8" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

and then add

```
'post_author' => $current_user->ID
```

to your $new_post array.

then you can use

```
<p>Posted by: <?php the_author(); ?></p>
```

Comment: Glad i can help

Comment: Actually, I can see the use who posted the article in the admin, but in the post, it's blank.

Comment: here's my backend code: https://gist.github.com/d5b35d46114b20d73639

Comment: the backend is the admin and you said you can see it there. if you mean the front end then add <p>Posted by: <?php the_author(); ?></p>
to your loop

Comment: changed to <p>Posted by: ".$current_user->user_name."</p> and that worked perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: but that wont display what user posted only what user is logged in.

Comment: the form grabs the user name from the logged in user, then prints it to the post :) check this out: https://gist.github.com/5bd58efb6d99a41e133f

Comment: ok and what is the question?

Comment: ah, no, no question. Justy demonstrating how I finally got it to work. Thanks!!

Comment: @Unfortunately: ok, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user is logged in, then wp_insert_post should automatically set the post author field properly. Have you tried just calling the_author() to output the author of the posts name?